# Powering one light switch from another

Tags: electrical, switch

[image]
 i have two single pole switches about 12 feet apart with power coming in to one switch. I want to connect that power to the second switch. I did it using diagram attached. It works. (I use connectors - the little squares on diagram. Used Orange for white wire.). Each switch just turns on/off the light connected to switch without affecting other.

I am concerned that when i check each black wire on switch has power whether switch is on or off and that doesnt seem right. I thought wire going to light should only be hot when switch is ON.[image]

Comment: You can crop screenshots from your phone so that we just get the picture and not all the extra distractions to scroll past.

Comment: If we assume the top rectangle to be a wire nut, this should not work. The top lamp would always be fed by the black and white wires. You diagram seems wrong

Comment: @JPhi1618 maybe this is a very subtle advert for WSOP?

Comment: If your drawing is accurate, top light will be on 24x7 *(not that there's anything wrong with that, now with 5 watt LEDs I am hardwiring certain safety lights)* - and bottom light will only light if both switches are on.

Comment: Sorry for the artwork. Might be more help to ignore completely and solve the problem, which is:        i have incoming power to one switch and i need to get power from there to another switch. Each switch is single pole controlling one light.

Comment: How are you checking for power?

Comment: Checking for power using a digital electric detector. On other switches i detect power on one black terminal only unless switch is on. But in my circuit its detecting power on both switch terminals whether light on or not. Otherwise switches working fine. Is there a way to upload another (clearer) diagram?